# Programmatically create a multipartformdatainput

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I have a javax RestEasy endpoint to accept file uploads:

```
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@POST
Upload create(MultipartFormDataInput input);
```

I'm using a ResteasyClientBuilder to proxy the endpoint interface class so I can call it via

```
MultipartFormDataInput sampleData;
uploadEndpoint.create(sampleData);
```

However, there does not seem to be a simple way of creating a multipartformdatainput.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a simple way. The documentation [writes about MultipartFormDataInput](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html_single/#MultipartFormData):

> When writing a JAX-RS service, RESTEasy provides an interface that allows you to read in multipart/form-data mime type.

For the client side there is [MultipartFormDataOutput](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html_single/#multipart_formdata_output):

> RESTEasy provides a simple API to output multipart/form-data.

I don't know a way to convert from Output to Input. You could implement `MultipartFormDataInput` on your own or use `MultiPartFormDataInputImpl` which comes with a `parse(InputStream is)` method. Then you would have to create a (Multipart)InputStream manually.

I think the easier way in this case is not to use the Proxy Framework or use [a Map](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html_single/#multipart_map) or a [@MultipartForm](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html_single/#multipartform_annotation) in you interface.